# Pokemon go gmail login help

Tags: pokemon-go

I open the app and it prompts me to log in with my gmail account. After I do that, a server is busy screen appears but my friends who log in via gmail at the same time get in the app. I have tried restarting my iPhone and reinstalling the app. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Log in to your gmail in safari. Then, open the game. Before you click on "Allow", go to the lower right of the screen, and open it in Safari. Do the whole process in Safari. Pay attention, because for a split second it'll ask you if you want to open it in the Pokémon Go app. Click yes, and go to the app. The game will work fine.